# LDAP User Change Password on Next Login and Sync with Azure AD

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap, azure-active-directory

Hi I'm currently using LDAP with Azure Ad Connect using C#

I have no issue when it comes to assigning a password to AD and syncing said password with Azure AD.
However, I run into a issue when trying to enforce "User Change password on next login".

I can set the reset property for the directory user using:

```
user.Properties["pwdLastSet"].Value = 0;
```

But when I do, I can't sign in to Azure AD using my old password so that the reset triggers.

Can anyone assist me with the issue?

Comment: *"I can't sign in to Azure AD"* - How are you signing in?

Comment: through the azure portal

Answer (score 0):

When you sync the user in on-premise AD to Azure AD, the `PwdLastSet` attribute will be synchronized as `LastPasswordChangeTimestamp` in Azure AD.

If you want the user must change his password on the next login, you need to set the `forceChangePasswordNextSignIn` in [`passwordProfile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/passwordprofile?view=graph-rest-1.0) of the AAD user object after sync.

In your case, you could use the [Microsoft Graph SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#example-2-update-properties-of-the-specified-user), create an [authentication provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS), use sample:

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var user = new User
{
    PasswordProfile = new PasswordProfile
    {
        ForceChangePasswordNextSignIn = true
    }
};

await graphClient.Users["{id}"]
    .Request()
    .UpdateAsync(user);
```

**Note:** When updating the `passwordProfile` property, the `Directory.AccessAsUser.All` permission is required, it is just available as `Delegated permission`, it means you could not use [`Client credentials provider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS#client-credentials-provider).

Fore more details, you could refer to Microsoft Graph - [Update user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

Comment: Does only passwordprofile need to be set, or does both passwordprofile and pwdlastset have to be set?

Comment: sorry nothing sure yet, it seems we need to set the permission on AzureAd (besides just the directory.accessasuser.all) but we don't want to touch the permission just yet (the higher ups are talking about it), will try to remember to update this thread when we get it working.